# Global symbol "%properties" requires explicit package name

Tags: perl

when I use strict, I get below compilation issue otherwise it works fine. I tried to place 'my' keyword for properties but this is not fixing it. Is something i'm doing wrong?

```
#Read properties file
open( F, 'properties' )
  or die "properties file is missing in current directory. Error:  $!\n";
while (<F>) {
    next if (/^\#/);
    (my $name, my $val ) = m/(\w+)\s*=(.+)/;
    my $properties{ trim($name) } = trim($val);
}
close(F);
my $current_host = $properties{host_server};
my $token        = $properties{server_token};
my $state        = 'success';
my $monitor_freq = $properties{monitor_frequency};
```

Error

```
syntax error at Q:/IDE/Eclipse_Workspace/ICEFaces/Server_Client_Mon/Server_Client_Mon.pl line 22, near "$properties{ "
Global symbol "$val" requires explicit package name at Q:/IDE/Eclipse_Workspace/ICEFaces/Server_Client_Mon/Server_Client_Mon.pl line 22.
Global symbol "%properties" requires explicit package name at Q:/IDE/Eclipse_Workspace/ICEFaces/Server_Client_Mon/Server_Client_Mon.pl line 25.
Global symbol "%properties" requires explicit package name at Q:/IDE/Eclipse_Workspace/ICEFaces/Server_Client_Mon/Server_Client_Mon.pl line 26.
Global symbol "%properties" requires explicit package name at Q:/IDE/Eclipse_Workspace/ICEFaces/Server_Client_Mon/Server_Client_Mon.pl line 28.
Global symbol "%properties" requires explicit package name at Q:/IDE/Eclipse_Workspace/ICEFaces/Server_Client_Mon/Server_Client_Mon.pl line 32.
```

Comment: You cannot assign to a hash key during declaration of the variable. You must always do `my %hash; $hash{foo} = ...` in two lines, unless you assign the entire hash at once: `my %hash = (foo => bar, baz => baaz);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

move the declaration outside the loop

```
my %properties;
while(...) {
    ...
    $properties{ trim($name) } = trim($val)
}
```

Comment: what if I have sub like below sub client_monitor_state() {
 my $token = $properties{token}; } , it cannot find properties right? How to fix this?

Comment: It can find it if the `my %properties;` comes before it.

Comment: Don't use prototypes unless you know what they do (the empty parens after your sub name).

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
open my $fh, '<', 'properties' or die "Unable to open properties file: $!";

my %properties;
while (<$fh>) {
  next if /^#/;
  my ($name, $val) = map trim($_), split /=/, $_, 2;
  $properties{$name} = $val;
}
my ($current_host, $token, $monitor_freq) =
    @properties{qw/ host_server server_token monitor_frequency /};
my $state = 'success';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind little bit extra memory usage,

```
my %properties = map {
  /^#/ ? () 
       : map trim($_), /(\w+)\s*=(.+)/;
}
<F>;
```

or

```
my %properties =
  map trim($_),
  map /(\w+)\s*=(.+)/,
  grep !/^#/, <F>;
```

Comment: … but you were really trying to say `my $properties = map trim($_), map /(\w+)\s*=(.+)/, grep !/^#/, <F>`.

Comment: @amon if you meant `%properties` then yes. Are there any cons to multiple maps/greps?

Comment: Sorry, of course I meant the hash. Yes, there are disadvantages for using `map` and `grep` because all such list operations store the whole intermediate data on the stack – but our two solutions are equivalent in this respect. My comment just wanted to point out that `map { COND ? EXPR : () }` is more idomatically expressed as `map {EXPR} grep {COND}`. Furthermore, a nested `map` in “tail position” can be flattened out: `map { map B($_), A($_) }` is the same as `map B($_), map A($_)`.

Comment: @amon ok so memory for stack(or heap?) is being reused between multiple maps? And how costly in terms of speed/memory is calling multiple maps when dealing with large lists?

Comment: This is all getting a bit off topic :) Using fewer loops is generally cheaper, but it doesn't usually change the algorithmic complexity. A problem with `map` is that it uses the stack both for in- and output which is of course worse for large lists: The output gradually replaces the input from bottom up (it's effectively `splice`d into the stack), but if a map expression returns multiple values, this causes remaining input values to be copied upwards (`map` is worst-case *O(n²)* time). This means that nested map is probably better if the nested expr returns multiple values – not the case here.

Comment: @amon tnx, but here map is returning two elements for each line from filehandle.